# PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object

Tags: php, select, mysqli

I just started re-programming of my existing functions for using mysqli.
Simple mysqli request like:

```
$select = $mysqli->query("SELECT name, id FROM countries WHERE id > 0");
while ($row = $select->fetch_assoc())
{
  $country_name = $row['name'];
  $country_id = $row['id'];
  $items .= "<country_id>$country_id</country_id><country_name>$country_name</country_name>";
}
```

work fine, but last 2 hours I am trying to make work this complicated request:

```
function skype_users($api_id,$filter,$limit,$offset,$my_country,$my_city)
{
  global $mysqli;

  $select = $mysqli->query("SELECT co.name AS country, ci.name AS city, us.user_id, us.user_nickname, us.user_sex, us.avatar_id, sk.skype_id, sk.comment, us.user_birthday, us.country_id, us.city_id 
  FROM countries co, cities ci, users us, skype_users sk 
  WHERE us.country_id = co.id AND us.city_id = ci.id AND us.user_id = sk.user_id AND sk.active = 1 AND us.user_sex = '$filter' AND us.country_id = '$my_country'
  ORDER BY sk.id DESC LIMIT $limit OFFSET $offset");

  while ($row = $select->fetch_assoc())
  {
    $country = $row['country'];
    $city = $row['city'];
    $user_id = $row['user_id'];
    $user_nickname = $row['user_nickname'];
    $user_sex = $row['user_sex'];
    $avatar_id = $row['avatar_id'];
    $user_birthday = $row['user_birthday'];
    $country_id = $row['country_id'];
    $city_id = $row['city_id'];
    $comment = $row['comment'];
    $skype_id = $row['skype_id'];

    $items .= "
    <country>$country</country>
    <city>$city</city>
    <userId>$user_id</userId>
    <userNickName>$user_nickname</userNickName>
    <userSex>$user_sex</userSex>
    <avatarId>$avatar_id</avatarId>
    <userBirthday>$user_birthday</userBirthday>
    <userCountryId>$country_id</userCountryId>
    <userCityId>$city_id</userCityId>
    <skypeComment>$comment</skypeComment>
    <skypeId>$skype_id</skypeId>";
  }

  return $items;
}
```

Its sends me an error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function `fetch_assoc()` on a non-object  on line 10.

Line 10 is:

```
while ($row = $select->fetch_assoc())
```

Comment: I swear this *same* question is asked like 3 times each day (have a look at the "Related" questions on the right side of this page).  Anyway, you need to add error checking.  You can't just *assume* your query worked.  `if($select === FALSE){ die($mysqli->error); }`.

Comment: 2 hours I look at related questions and use Google search and try all variants. Its not work. error checking added - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-1' at line 4

Comment: It sounds like either `$limit` or `$offset` is `-1`, which isn't allowed.

Comment: I think that qualifies as the answer, @Barmar

Comment: $limit=10 and $offset=0, When I put request to PhpMyAdmin its work fine - Showing rows 0 - 9 (10 total, Query took 0.0162 sec)

Comment: Please post the contents of the SQL query string after all the variables are substituted.

Comment: SELECT co.name AS country, ci.name AS city, us.user_id, us.user_nickname, us.user_sex, us.avatar_id, sk.skype_id, sk.comment, us.user_birthday, us.country_id, us.city_id 
FROM countries co, cities ci, users us, skype_users sk 
WHERE us.country_id = co.id AND us.city_id = ci.id AND us.user_id = sk.user_id AND sk.active = 1 AND us.user_sex = '0' AND us.country_id = '1'
ORDER BY sk.id DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0

Comment: That can't be right. The error message says `near '-1'`, but there's no `-1` in that query.

Comment: Hmmm! When offset = 0 its set it to -1 when = 1 or 100 its work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$sql = "SELECT co.name AS country, ci.name AS city, us.user_id, us.user_nickname, us.user_sex, us.avatar_id, sk.skype_id, sk.comment, us.user_birthday, us.country_id, us.city_id 
        FROM countries co, cities ci, users us, skype_users sk 
        WHERE us.country_id = co.id AND us.city_id = ci.id AND us.user_id = sk.user_id AND sk.active = 1 AND us.user_sex = '$filter' AND us.country_id = '$my_country'
        ORDER BY sk.id DESC");
if ($limit > 0 && $offset >= 0) {
    $sql .= " LIMIT $limit OFFSET $offset";
}
$select = $mysqli->query($sql) or die ($mysqli->error);
```

This should prevent specifying a negative value to `LIMIT` or `OFFSET`.

Comment: Hmmm! When offset = 0 its set it to -1 when = 1 or 100 its work fine. thank you!

Comment: I don't understand that. Nothing changes `0` to `-1`.

Comment: Because I have mistake in another line - if (empty($offset)) $offset = '-1'; So, 0 = empty Thanks! Your answer help me find a problem. You saw my life :)

Answer (score -2):

cause your function dont see mysqli object. You should create object (connection) in function or pass as argument

```
function skype_users($api_id,$filter,$limit,$offset,$my_country,$my_city)
{
   $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

   $select = $mysqli->query("SELECT co.name AS country, ci.name AS city, us.user_id, us.user_nickname, us.user_sex, us.avatar_id, sk.skype_id, sk.comment, us.user_birthday, us.country_id, us.city_id 
   FROM countries co, cities ci, users us, skype_users sk 
   WHERE us.country_id = co.id AND us.city_id = ci.id AND us.user_id = sk.user_id AND        sk.active = 1 AND us.user_sex = '$filter' AND us.country_id = '$my_country'
   ORDER BY sk.id DESC LIMIT $limit OFFSET $offset");
```

pass mysqli object as argument to function:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

function skype_users($api_id,$filter,$limit,$offset,$my_country,$my_city,$mysqli){

   $select = $mysqli->query("SELECT co.name AS country, ci.name AS city, us.user_id, us.user_nickname, us.user_sex, us.avatar_id, sk.skype_id, sk.comment, us.user_birthday, us.country_id, us.city_id 
   FROM countries co, cities ci, users us, skype_users sk 
   WHERE us.country_id = co.id AND us.city_id = ci.id AND us.user_id = sk.user_id AND        sk.active = 1 AND us.user_sex = '$filter' AND us.country_id = '$my_country'
   ORDER BY sk.id DESC LIMIT $limit OFFSET $offset");

   ....
}
```

Comment: He has `global $mysqli` in his function. If the problem were with `$mysqli`, the error would be from `query`, not `fetch_assoc`.